# Jackson XML Unable to deserialize list

Tags: xml, kotlin, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I try to parse XML like this:

```
fun main() {
val kotlinXmlMapper = XmlMapper(JacksonXmlModule().apply {
    setDefaultUseWrapper(false)
}).registerKotlinModule()
        .configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true)
        .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)

val value: Feed = kotlinXmlMapper.readValue("""
    <feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
      <entry>
        <id>Test-1</id>
        <title>Test</title>
        <summary type="html">Test</summary>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <id>Test-2</id>
        <title>Test2</title>
        <summary type="html">Test2</summary>
      </entry>
    </feed>
""".trimIndent(), Feed::class.java)
println(value)}
```

My data classes looks like this:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName="feed")
data class Feed(
        @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName="entry")
        @JsonProperty("entry")
        val entry: List<Entry>)

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName="entry")
data class Entry(val id: String, val title: String, val summary: String)
```

I thought I annotate the list element with `JacksonXmlElementWrapper` and then it should work. but unfortunately not:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `service.Entry` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('Test-1')
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 3, column: 15] (through reference chain: service.Feed["entry"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
```

Have anybody an idea/suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to parse it without `Feed` class. Just as a list: `List<Entry>`. Take a look on this `Java` example: [Parsing XML to Java Object Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62646439/parsing-xml-to-java-object-node/62647544#62647544)

Comment: @MichałZiober Awesome! Now it works! Can you add an answer with some explanation why it's now working? Then I can accept the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `XML`, by default list items are wrapped by an extra node. This node does not represent extra class in `POJO` model, so, we can skip it. You need to represent in `POJO` model only `item` node and specify to `Jackson` that you want to read payload as a list of these nodes:

```
val genres = kotlinXmlMapper.readValue<List<Entry>>(json)
```

See also:

- [How to use jackson to deserialize to Kotlin collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33368328/how-to-use-jackson-to-deserialize-to-kotlin-collections)
- [How do I deserialize JSON into a List with Kotlin + Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34716697/how-do-i-deserialize-json-into-a-listsometype-with-kotlin-jackson)