# jackson objectMapper how to set exact return type of Map

Tags: json, kotlin, jackson, mapping

Is there a way to tell Jackson objectMapper exactly what kind of Map I want to get?

Right now I have to cast my result Map like this:

```
objectMapper.convertValue(this, Map::class.java) as Map<String, Any>
```

which I'm not a big fan of, so is there a way to tell objectMapper that I want to get `Map<String, Any>` and not `Map<*, *>?`

Or maybe there is another way of converting some object to Map<String,Any> representing json-like structure?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify type like this:

```kotlin
val convertedValue = objectMapper.convertValue<Map<String, Any>>(this)
```

See also:

- [Jackson XML Unable to deserialize list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62728672/jackson-xml-unable-to-deserialize-list/62746219#62746219)
- [How do I deserialize JSON into a List with Kotlin + Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34716697/how-do-i-deserialize-json-into-a-listsometype-with-kotlin-jackson)